# Creating test project for WCF REST web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, testing

I have a C# WCF Restful service that I want to create a test project for. I'm more interested in doing an integration test, ie having the test class start up the WCF service in a local ServiceHost object, then creating a link to a client proxy and being able to test the service calls as if they were being called from an MVC website controller, passing in the same parameters that the MVC website will have to use and returning the deserialised data types from the WCF service call.

The criteria I want to test are

1) Correct serialisation/deserialisation of complex objects returned

2) Authentication per call - as it is a REST service (can skip this for now just to get the pipes working first of all but later will add this)

3) Correct behaviour of REST service behaviour, ie certain methods only being allowed for GET, PUT, DELETE HTTP method

4) Data from service methods returned correctly across the wire, no problems with detached data, object graphs from EF etc

Could anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial or example of how to do this or if you have the time, to explain it here? I'm not sure of the best way to go about this.

Many thanks

Comment: Seems like there are not many tutorials.. you could combine intro to REST testing with some intro on WCF or other client. After all, your (test) client could be RestSharp, WCF-REST-Based or any other REST solution. As for the startup, just treat it like a process (an .exe you start), you might have to write a small wrapper. Then just focuson testing literature and REST testing.